# How to replace a part of an expression with left part of the corresponding equation?

Tags: python, sympy

When I do:

```
from sympy import *
from sympy.abc import *
init_printing()

c = a + b
d = 1/3 * c**3
e = d.diff(a)
```

I see for `e`:

e = (a + b)<sup>2</sup>

but want to see something like:

e = c<sup>2</sup>

How can I tell sympy what I need?

Comment: The key point is that `c = a + b` is not an equation with a left and right hand sides; it's just  Python assignment by way of which c is assigned the object a+b. Equations are represented as `Eq(lhs, rhs)` in SymPy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I need justto use `subs`, just for showing purposes I use 'c':

e_with_c = e.subs(c, 'c')

will be displayed as:

e_with_c = 1.0c<sup>2</sup>